# How does Django query the tree structure

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and I am creating a blog and comment function

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200)


class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

This is my current test data

```
Comment.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet [
{'id': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'content': '1'}, 
{'id': 2, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'content': '2'}, 
{'id': 3, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': 1,    'content': '1-1'}, 
{'id': 4, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': 1,    'content': '1-2'}
]>
```

But now I want to find out such a tree structure, what should I do?

```
[
 {'id': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'content': '1', 'children': [
            {'id': 3, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': 1, 'content': '1-1'},
            {'id': 4, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': 1, 'content': '1-2'}
        ]},
 {'id': 2, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'content': '2', 'children': [] },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can' t obtain a nested dictionary with `values`.
You could write this:

```py
Comment.objects.all().values('id', 'user_id', 'blog_id', 'parent_id', 'content', 'children')
```

But the result will not be as you expected, the list will contain a dict for every parent-child combination, for example:

```py
[
{'id': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'content': '1', children: 2}, 
{'id': 1, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': None, 'content': '1', children: 3}, 
{'id': 2, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': 1, 'content': '2', children: None}, 
{'id': 3, 'user_id': 1, 'blog_id': 1, 'parent_id': 1, 'content': '2', children: None}, 
]
```

You can deal directly with the queryset, for example:

```py
for comment in Comment.objects.all().prefetch_related('children'):
    for child in comment.children.all():
        print(child.id)
```

Or you can use a nested list comprehension (the result will be as you expected):

```py
print([{'id': comment.id, 'user_id': comment.user.id, 'blog_id': comment.blog.id, 'parent_id': comment.parent.id if comment.parent != None else None, 'content': comment.content, 'children': [{'id':
child.id, 'user_id': child.user.id, 'blog_id': child.blog.id, 'parent_id': child.parent.id, 'content': child.content} for child in comment.children.all()]} for comment in Comment.objects.all()])
```

Comment: After reading your answer, I used recursion to query, and finally the tree structure I wanted was queried. Can you help me see what improvements are needed in my current code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use recursion to query

```py
def get_children(c):
    return {
        'id': c.id,
        'user_id': c.user_id,
        'blog_id': c.blog_id,
        'parent_id': c.parent_id,
        'content': c.content,
        'children': list(map(get_children, c.children.all())),
    }


def get_comment_tree():
    return list(map(get_children, Comment.objects.filter(parent=None).prefetch_related('children')))
```

Output json

```json
[{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "blog_id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
    "content": "1",
    "children": [{
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "blog_id": 1,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "content": "1-1",
        "children": [{
            "id": 5,
            "user_id": 1,
            "blog_id": 1,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "content": "1-1-1",
            "children": []
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 1,
        "blog_id": 1,
        "parent_id": 1,
        "content": "1-2",
        "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 1,
    "blog_id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
    "content": "2",
    "children": []
}]
```

Comment: To further decrease the database hit you could also use `select_related`:  `Comment.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True).select_related('user', 'blog').prefetch_related('children')`. I think your implementation works. Depending on what you need to do with comments, maybe you could use other simpler solutions. If you need to display info in a template you could pass directly the queryset (the one is written earlier) in the template context and iterate through it in the template. If you are creating an API you could use a Django Rest Framework serializer.